# How to get currency code from priceLocale ( sample 120￥)?

Tags: storekit

After fetch items from StoreKit , we can get that item price (sample 120¥)
How to get currency code (JPY) from priceLocale ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After refer [NSLocale](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSLocale/objectForKey:) 's [Constant](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/NSLocale_Component_Keys) i find how to get that value.

```
        NSLocale *loc = d[@"priceLocale"];
        NSString *currencyCode = [loc objectForKey:NSLocaleCurrencyCode];
```